# Что лучше использовать widget или shortcut?

Tags: android

Как можно добиться такого эффекта? Представьте, что у меня есть значок приложения на рабочем столе android, и когда приходит сообщение, я получаю ярлык с этим сообщением от этого значка. От вас мне нужно знать, как можно реализовать подобную вещь, например widget или shortcut?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

Можно сделать так (у меня тут пример достаточно примитивный, так что дизайн потом поменяйте на свой вкус, например, Toast можно заменить [чем-нибудь таким](http://www.materialdoc.com/alerts/) `:)`).

Создаёте кастомный layout для вывода сообщения:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/custom_toast_container"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:padding="8dp"
              android:background="#DAAA"
    >
    <ImageView android:src="@mipmap/ic_cat"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:textColor="#FFF"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Создаёте службу для получения сообщения:

```
public class ToastService extends IntentService {
    Handler mHandler;

    public ToastService() {
        super("ToastService");
        mHandler = new Handler();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        String message = intent.getStringExtra("task");
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mHandler.post(new DisplayToast(this, message));

    }
}
```

Добавляете её в манифест:

```
<application>
     ...
     <service
            android:name=".ToastService"
            android:exported="false"/>
</application>
```

И создаёте поток для отображения сообщения:

```
public class DisplayToast implements Runnable {
    private final Context mContext;
    String mText;

    public DisplayToast(Context mContext, String text){
        this.mContext = mContext;
        mText = text;
    }

    public void run(){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast, null);
        View container = layout.findViewById( R.id.custom_toast_container);

        TextView text = (TextView) container.findViewById(R.id.text);
        text.setText("Вы получили новое сообщение: " + mText);

        Toast toast = new Toast(mContext);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
        toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.setView(layout);
        toast.show();

    }
}
```

И соответственно, для проверки работы можете в том же приложении в любой активности создать намерение:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Запускаем свой IntentService
    Intent intentMyIntentService = new Intent(this, ToastService.class);
    startService(intentMyIntentService.putExtra("task", "не забудь покормить кота!"));
}
```

После запуска можно свернуть приложение и получаем на главном экране сообщение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]